Mass Transit : EF Core outbox not persisting messages
I have been googling this for a while and can't seem to find a solution, this seems to line up with the Mass Transit docs.  Mass transit works perfectly in my project but as soon as I add the SQL server outbox it doesn't write anything to the tables and no publishing takes place.  Here is how I register Mass Transit :
_services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
{
    busConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    busConfigurator.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ISomeApplicationMarker>();

    busConfigurator.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<SomeDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer();
        options.UseBusOutbox();
    });

    busConfigurator.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((IRegistrationContext context, string name, IReceiveEndpointConfigurator cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseEntityFrameworkOutbox<SomeDbContext>(context);
    });

    busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
    {
        var settings = context.GetRequiredService<MessageBrokerSettings>();

        configurator.Host(new Uri(settings.Host), h =>
        {
            h.Username(settings.Username);
            h.Password(settings.Password);
        });

        configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

I also have this in the Db Context's OnModelCreating :
modelBuilder.AddTransactionalOutboxEntities();

The way all my publishing takes place is through an EF Core interceptor that captures domain event emitted by the model :
public override async ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData, int result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var bus = _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEventBus>();

    var context = eventData.Context;

    if (context is null)
        return await base.SavedChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);

    var events = context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<AggregateRoot>()
        .Select(a => a.Entity)
        .Where(e => e.GetDomainEvents() is not null)
        .SelectMany(e =>
        {
            var domainEvents = e.GetDomainEvents();

            e.ClearDomainEvents();

            return domainEvents;
        });

    foreach(var domainEvent in events)
        await bus.PublishAsync(domainEvent, cancellationToken);

    return await base.SavedChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}

Lastly, my IEventBus implementation looks like this :
public async Task PublishAsync(object message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Publishing event {@Event}", message);

    await _endpoint.Publish(message, (context) =>
    {
        context.Headers.Set("jwtToken", _contextAccessor.GetJwtTokenFromAuthHeader());
    }, cancellationToken);
}

The _endpoint is an injected IPublishEndpoint in that class.
Again, everything works perfectly without the outbox.  What am I doing wrong?

The sample works, I'd suggest reviewing the logs (DEBUG) to see what MT's doing and ensure you're properly injected scoped services to your dependencies, and that all your dependencies are properly registered as scoped.

Also, using the outbox without UseMessageRetry is a sure way to back yourself into a corner, always use it.

my EF Core interceptor is registered as a singleton and  creates the scope using IServiceProvider.  Could that be the issue?

Seems highly suspect, if you search for MassTransit and interceptor you'll find other post of people having issues with them and changing their approach entirely.

I changed nothing other than making my EventBus abstraction a singleton and making it use IBus instead of IPublishEndpoint and it works now!  Is there any difference between the 2 when it comes to integrating with the outbox?

IBus is not going through the outbox.
